# No such middleware to insert after: "ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

Recently I have migrated an Old Ruby Project (Ruby 2.2.5, Rails 4.2.7.1) to the latest version.

I followed the below steps to do this,

1. Deleted the GEM.lock File
2. Removed the version numbers in the GEM file
3. Reran "bundle install" command.

Now I am unable to run "rake db:migrate" command as it is throwing me the below error.

```
rake aborted!
No such middleware to insert after: "ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions"
```

But other projects in my repo ran successfully. I tried the "bundle exec rake db:migrate" command instead of "rake db:migrate" command. But didn't help.

I get the same error when I run

```
rake middleware
```

My current versions are Ruby 2.6.7 and Rails 6.1.4

Please help me.

Comment: have you check any code in your config folder, try to find `ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions`

Comment: Yes, I have searched the entire project folder. I couldn't find this.

Comment: Update: When I commented airbrake gem, I didn't get this error. But curious why this is causing an issue. But I am getting below error now                                    
 C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/set.rb:367:in `delete': can't modify rbtree in iteration (TypeError)
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/set.rb:367:in `delete'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:570:in `block in run_timers'